# QML Treeview with QFileSystemModel: cannot set root folder

Tags: c++, qt, qml, treeview

I am trying to use the QML Treeview in Qt 6.3 to display a folder structure.
I have set up a C++ backend with QFileSystemModel and the Treeview can actually display the contents of the folder structure that I selected in QFileSystemModel. The only problem is that the selected folder is not at the root of the folder structure. Let's say I use /home/user/test/ as root path in QFileSystemModel, then the root of the folder structure in Treeview is actually / instead of /home/user/test/ .
It seems that in Qt 5 there was an option to set a property "rootIndex" on the Treeview, but this doesn't exist in Qt 6.3? Is there any option to achieve the same in the Qt 6.3 Treeview ?

Comment: please provide [mcve] so we can run and test it.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108541 check the comment